# how do I use download_test_data()?

Tags: catkin, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to migrate a rosbuild [package](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/master/velodyne_driver) to catkin. It has unit tests which require moderately large data files stored on **pr.willowgarage.com**. The rosbuild version did it like this:

```
rosbuild_download_test_data(
  http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/velodyne/32e.pcap
  tests/32e.pcap
  e41d02aac34f0967c03a5597e1d554a9
  )
```

So, I changed that to invoke `download_test_data()` with identical parameters.

But, my tests can't find the data. Formerly they did it this way:

```
<!-- start read with example PCAP file -->
<node pkg="velodyne_driver" type="velodyne_node" name="velodyne_node">
  <param name="model" value="32E"/>
  <param name="pcap" value="$(find velodyne_driver)/tests/32e.pcap"/>
</node>
```

Now it fails:

```
[FATAL] [1369196347.360283641]: Error opening Velodyne socket dump file.
```

I finally discovered a `download_data_tests_32e.pcap` make target. Invoking it explicitly reads the file into the build tree, and similarly for another test file.

Several related questions:

1. Where is `download_test_data()` documented?
2. How do it get the the unit test build targets to depend on the download targets?
3. What do I use instead of `$(find velodyne_driver)/tests/32e.pcap` to resolve the path name?

**UPDATE**: The download command puts the data here in the build tree: `~/ros/wet/hydro/build/velodyne/velodyne_driver/tests/32e.pcap`, which seems reasonable.

But, rospack resolves to the source tree:

```
$ rospack find velodyne_driver 
/home/joq/ros/wet/hydro/src/velodyne/velodyne_driver
```

Is that why `$(find velodyne_driver)/tests/32e.pcap` does not work?

Also, experiment reveals an answer to question 2: the `tests` and `run_tests` build targets *do* depend on the download targets, but the more specific `run_tests_velodyne_driver` target does not.

**UPDATE2**: I tried to hack around the problem by using an absolute file name in **/tmp**:

```
download_test_data(
  http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/velodyne/32e.pcap
  /tmp/${PROJECT}/tests/32e.pcap
  e41d02aac34f0967c03a5597e1d554a9)
```

But, download_test_data() insists on prefixing the name with ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/, even when it is fully qualified. It always goes in the build tree, although it cannot be resolved there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63189/how-do-i-use-download_test_data()?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-22**:
There does not appear to be any documentation for this function, but the source is located here: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/groovy-devel/cmake/test/download_test_data.cmake

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-22**:
I looked at the source, that's the only way I got as far as I did. But, it's not exactly self-explanatory. I also found other packages doing similar things, presumably successfully.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-22**:
Yeah, I figured, but I don't have answers to your other questions yet.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-22**:
OK. Thanks for the help. I'll keep working on it. I want to write a how-to page for this, if I can figure out how. :-)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-22**:
That would be appreciated, I'll try to polish this process for 0.4, but as it really affects a small number of users it hasn't been prioritized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Opened [catkin issue #426](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/426).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1